# RestKit and key-value coding ... how to address repeating elements?

Tags: ios, xml, restkit, key-value-coding

I've got a document that looks like this sometimes:

```
<doc>
  <titleInfo>
    <title>One version of the title</title>
  </titleInfo>
  <titleInfo>
    <title>Another version</title>
  </titleInfo>
</doc>
```

But other times it looks like this:

```
<doc>
  <titleInfo>
    <title>This is the only version of the title</title>
  </titleInfo>
</doc>
```

I'm trying to map this to an array in my object with the following:

```
[mapping mapKeyPath:@"titleInfo.title" toAttribute:@"titles"];
```

This works in the first case, but on the second case I receive

`RKObjectMappingOperation.m:199 Failed transformation of value at keyPath 'titleInfo.title'. No strategy for transforming from '__NSCFString' to 'NSArray'`

Clearly RestKit is correctly interpreting the first document as containing an array of strings -- but in the case of the second document, I can't find a way to force that same interpretation.

Is there a simple way to express this with the KVC facilities in RestKit, or am I better off writing some entirely custom mapper?

Comment: which version of restkit do you use? the 0.9.3 snapshot from the website or git master?

Comment: I followed the tl;dr instructions in the readme -- git://github.com/RestKit/RestKit.git

Comment: I ran into the same problem and created [an issue on github](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/536)

Answer (score 0):

As per Blake Walters: The LibXML parser on master and in 0.9.3 has had numerous issues and was recently replaced with an NSXMLParser based solution in the development branch of RestKit and this solves some issues.

**The better method is to wrap the repeating elements into an array for access.**

Comment: I assume that means changing the XML, which can't happen.